# Why forward and redirect in grails don't stop initial action execution?

Tags: grails, redirect, forward

I read about [forward](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Controllers/forward.html) and [redirect](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Controllers/redirect.html) in Grails and don't understant why the code bellow prints "foo".

See:

```
def bar = {
   redirect (controller: "public", action: "index") // same happens with forward
   println "foo" // prints this in console?? WHY?
}
```

In my opinion redirect/forward must skip current method execution...

Is this a bug or I understand the concept wrong?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Because these are [just function calls](http://docs.grails.org/latest/guide/theWebLayer.html#redirectsAndChaining) - they can't exit from a calling function (your action). Just put `return` afterwards.

Comment: do you mean

`return redirect(controller: 'foo', action: 'bar')`

Comment: or `redirect(controller: 'a'); return;` - either way will work, as you don't need action to return value after `redirect()`.