# Return a redirect or forward

Tags: grails

I have done some research about this
[Stop initial action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5805535/why-forward-and-redirect-in-grails-dont-stop-initial-action-execution)

But it doesn't satisfy me.
I have tried:

```
 forward(controller:"subtask", action:"create")
        return true
```

**Result :**

It returns the url but it's still on "subtask/create" page.
My question is how should I stop the redirect which I just want to **"redirect" my params to "subtask/create" but not redirect to that page**.

Comment: I don't understand your question. I suggest you check http://grails.asia/grails-redirect-vs-forward for a simple, straight to the point explanation of 'forward' vs 'redirect'.

Comment: pleasy, may you explain the question better ?

Comment: HI Guys, I am actually look for a way to stop or return the redirect. Something like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5805535/why-forward-and-redirect-in-grails-dont-stop-initial-action-execution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to think about your approach in a different way.

You want to send the parameters to the subtask create action ? or you just want to call it but you don't want your page to redirect and yet you are using a method to redirect.

It sounds like you are using a fork where you need a spoon.

Approach 1.

If you are attempting to call the method and pass the parameters. If they are on the same controller then make the create method call a private method in the controller that takes generic params. On the same controller rather than forward just call the same private method from this action. ?

approach 2:
If it is different controllers let the other controller carry out tasks via a service and call same service method here rather than redirect.

approach 3.
Using ajax either post to other url pre posting or after returning to your next action and do nothing with result.

You are currently forwarding/redirecting and saying you don't want to redirect well the answer is not to call redirect/forward if you don't wish to redirect/forward.